# val$context error in implement class

Tags: java, android

Here is my code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
import com.stericson.RootTools.RootTools;
import com.taidev.tawngpha.pllillopopfont.FontChanger.InstallFont;
import com.taidev.tawngpha.pllillopopfont.FontChanger.RestoreFont;

public class RootOkDialog{

public static void InstallFont(Context paramContext) {

    AlertDialog.Builder localBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(paramContext);
    localBuilder.setTitle("Ready?");
    localBuilder.setMessage("Are U Ready?");
    localBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(paramContext)
    {


        public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt)
        {
            new InstallFont(this.val$context).execute(new Void[0]);
        }
    });
    localBuilder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt)
        {
        }
    });
    localBuilder.show();
}
}
```

I want to show Dialog then when click `ok` button I want to run a new class `InstallFont`. But that show error at val$context. How should I do or fix this error.Please help me.
[here is my Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3C4Op.png)